# How to hash string in Blazor wasm?

Tags: .net-5, blazor-webassembly

In Net 5 Blazor client webassembly I can not use System.Security.Cryptography to compute SHA512.
What are working alternatives? So that some text hashed has the same hash on all browsers?

Comment: Why can't you use that class?  It's in standard 2.0 .

Comment: There's already a closed issue on the github page [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44996). There are still some options, like SHA256Managed or change the project target type to 'browser-wasm'. If these don't work you might have to implement it yourself or wait until .NET 6 release, i believe they're gonna fix it there :)

Answer (score 1):

I played around with blazor recently, and ran into this issue as well.

Sadly, the answer I found was this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/cryptography-apis-not-supported-on-blazor-webassembly

Currently the only workaround I see, is to create an API that does the hashing for you, and then call it using:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server

Answer (score 0):

Code below works in Blazor WASM.

```
static int GetDeterministicHashCode(this string str)
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash1 = (5381 << 16) + 5381;
        int hash2 = hash1;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 2)
        {
            hash1 = ((hash1 << 5) + hash1) ^ str[i];
            if (i == str.Length - 1)
                break;
            hash2 = ((hash2 << 5) + hash2) ^ str[i + 1];
        }

        return hash1 + (hash2 * 1566083941);
    }
}
```

Read this article for more info : https://andrewlock.net/why-is-string-gethashcode-different-each-time-i-run-my-program-in-net-core/